# How Change TextBox With myCustomTextBox in WPF datagrid cell editing mode

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, textbox, edit

I need to change default `TextBox` With `myCustomTextBox` in WPF data grid cell editing mode.

For example: When a user doubleclick on a cell, Show MyCustomControl instead WPF TextBox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cellediting template [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celleditingtemplate?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CellEditingTemplate">
            <local:myCustomTextBox Text="{Binding PropertyName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource CellEditingTemplate}"/>
</DataGrid>
```